# Algorithm for Swapping indices and simplifying the summand in a double sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, index

Say we have something like
$$ \sum_{p}^N\sum_{q}^N \cos(p) \sin(q) - \cos(q)\sin(p)  $$

usually, in the case like this, the indices p and q can be swapped, and the sum simplifies to 0.

I have an expression of a summand in mathematica with something similar to the expression above; but for now, how can I swap indices of the form below (without specifying an explicit `Sum[]` function)

```
Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p]
```

to be evaluated to`0`?

Comment: Is `Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p] /. {p -> q, q -> p}` what you are looking for?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That gives you the same thing but negative (i.e. `Cos[q]Sin[p] - Cos[p] Sin[q]` )

Comment: Yes, Tom, because the expression is antisymmetric in the indices... What about `n = 100;
Sum[Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p], {p, 1, n}, {q, 1, n}]
Sum[Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p], {p, 1, n}, {q, 1, n}]`?

Comment: Try `Clear[n]; Sum[Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p], {p, n}, {q, n}]`.  The transformation you seek seems like it might be built into `Sum`.

Comment: Actually, I find the question a bit confusing: You seem to say you want `Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p]` to evaluate to `0` without using `Sum`.  But that expression is definitely not `0`.  It's really only inside a symmetric double `Sum` that it adds up to zero.  (And that's what I guessed you meant in my previous comment.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I know that. It is addressed in the question too. The thing is that it is a very simple example which sum can evaluate easily, but the real problem I have in my hand is not contractible like that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The question is, if we have an expression which, for each of the terms the indices `p` and `q` are replaceable, how can I simplify them?

Comment: @Tom I'm still struggling to understand, but I think I might have it: Given expression `e`, you would like all terms that would sum to zero in the double sum to be removed from `e` -- is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, then?

```
removeantisymmetric = Function[e, (e + (e /. {p -> q, q -> p}))/2];

Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p] // removeantisymmetric // Simplify
(*  0  *)

Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p] + Cos[p] Cos[q] // removeantisymmetric // Simplify
(*  Cos[p] Cos[q]  *)
```

Strictly speaking `Simplify` is not needed on those examples.

Comment: This is simpler for two indices. But for greater no. of indices, one probably has to check with all possible pairs of antisymmetric indices.  Your method can be extended in those lines as well  I guess.

Comment: @Subho95 Are there more than two indices in a double sum?

Comment: Surely not. But I just wanted to say that in case the OP actually wants to evaluate multiple summation by taking cue from double summation, your method should be good with minor modifications.

Comment: @Subho95 Ah, I see. Somehow I find the description of the problem a bit confusing (to say that the nonzero term `Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p]` should evaluate to `0` outside the sum, then adding a curve to the example in the comment to your answer), and I'm just trying to home in on the problem the OP has in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following. This can be easily tweaked to work for any number of summation indices.

```
In[198]:= term[p_, q_] := -Cos[q] Sin[p] + Cos[p] Sin[q];

In[207]:= 
term[p, q] // 
 Assuming[Function[u, 
      term[p, q] == u] /@ (Function[u, term[u[[1]], u[[2]]]] /@ 
       Permutations[{p, q}]) // Simplify, Simplify@#] &

Out[207]= 0
```

**Update:**
This is not a good fix in my opinion. But the following will work:

```
In[316]:= ClearAll["Global`*"];

In[335]:= 
term[p_, q_] := -Cos[q] Sin[p] + Cos[p] Sin[q] + Cos[p]*Cos[q] + 
   5*Sin[p] Sin[q];
assumption = 
  Function[u, 
    term[p, q] == u] /@ (Function[u, term[u[[1]], u[[2]]]] /@ 
     Permutations[{p, q}]);
assumptiondup = Union[assumption, assumption // Simplify];

In[338]:= 

term[p, q] // Assuming[assumptiondup, Simplify@#] &

Out[338]= Cos[p] Cos[q] + 5 Sin[p] Sin[q]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but It fails when `term[p_,q_] = Cos[p] Sin[q] - Cos[q] Sin[p] + Cos[p] Cos[q]`

Comment: @Tom What do you want to have happen in that case?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's the same. I want to have it evaluated to be `Cos[p]Cos[q]` (or  `Cos[q]Cos[p]`) because that is the only term that survives after the double sum.

Comment: @Tom Then comment out the `// Simplify`.

Comment: I think what I needed was as simple as
`term{P_,Q_] = Cos[P] Sin[Q] -Cos[Q]Sin[P]`
`newterm = (term[P,Q] + term[Q,P])/2